# FCM Error Device token not registered/unregistered

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

After integrating with FCM i'm receiving push notification well, but suddenly i'm getting error from FCM says device token not registered.

Comment: This is a pretty vague question and not answerable as is. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: in my case there are conflicts between api keys, so recreated keys n now its fine